# 3.2 update causes strange swype problem

Tags: swype, samsung-galaxy-tab-10, 3.2-honeycomb

I own a galaxy tab 10.1. After updating to honeycomb 3.2, I have noticed the following problem whenever trying to use the swype keyboard in the url bar of the stock browser:
After having written any word using sliding, then the two last letters of that word are automatically erased if I try to tap any letter or the spacebar.

Has anyone else noticed this strange behavior?
Does anyone know how to fix this issue which is really very frustrating?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: After I've resolved Swype crashing following a Galaxy Tab hardware upgrade, I just want to share what might be the solution to a lot of Swype problems: try going into applications maintenance and clear Swype's application data.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that the spacing gets off in some fields, it will show extra spaces or back up over the last characters. Sometimes I have to use a different keyboard - the stock one or another tap keyboard.

Do you have the latest version of Skype Beta?  They put out a couple of them recently. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I currently have version v3.25.91.34889.34889.5238.GT_P7510. This comes preinstalled in galaxy tab 10.1, which means that I cannot upgrade to any newer version of swype.